# Amazon Scrape returning undefined nightmare package

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I am using nightmare.js to get the price for all the products in the database. When I try running just

```js
  const data = await monitor.find({})
  data.forEach(async (monitor1) => {
    const url = monitor1.Link
    console.log(url)
  })
```

It works, and console.logs many links, but when I try

```js
 data.forEach(async (monitor1) => {
    const url = monitor1.Link
    console.log(url)
     try {
      const priceString =  await nightmare.goto(monitor1.Link)
                                         .wait(".a-price-whole")
                                         .evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName("a-price-whole").innerText)
                                         .end()
      console.log(priceString)
    } catch (e) {
      throw e
    }
  
  })
```

It returns undefined for all the prices. The class is called a-price-whole as shown here
[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Scraping price by `.a-offscreen` class works for me.

```
 data.forEach(async (monitor1) => {
 const url = monitor1.Link
 console.log(url)
 try {
  const priceString =  await nightmare.goto(monitor1.Link)
                                     .wait(".a-offscreen")
                                     .evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName("a-offscreen").innerText)
                                     .end()
  console.log(priceString)
 } catch (e) {
   throw e
 }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Information is less, but I believe you are using same nightmare instance.
Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995486/calling-nightmarejs-in-a-loop/71397148#71397148)